# What is the best way to train a star jasmine up a wall?

Tags: wall, climbers, spacing

Also, what size wires would be used in terms of thickness and how far apart should they be spaced?

Comment: Star jasmine is a self-clinging climber, so wires as not the best supports because they are too slippery, A wooden trellis or a plastic mesh attached to the wall would be better.

Comment: There are quite a few sites on the internet that describe star jasmine as a self clinger. I dont know where they get their information from for I've actually seen these grow a few places and i can definitely say thats its a twinner by all means and not a self clinger.